# Infinite scrolling with Meteor-Pages

Tags: meteor

In my project I'm using Meteor-Pages to create infinite scrolling on the homepage. But I have a route to the tags articles and would like to apply this effect also.
How do I pass a parameter of the Iron-Router for Pagination?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just for the record here. I found a better solution for the infinite scrolling:
[Meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Infinite_Scrolling)

Doing it this way you can control the way you want.